# How to find ID in Jquery in DOM structure?

Tags: jquery

i have html like this, when i click on LIKE button i want to know `<div id="div17836463"`  how could i know that?

```
 <div class="MessageInfo">
        <div id="div17836463" class="Display">Display</div>
        <div class="Actions">
            <span><a class="like-Unlike" href="">Like</a></span> |
        </div>
    </div>
```

please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/mHJnH/2/

Comment: ID selector? $("#div17836463")? Or what?

Comment: @idk - Your fiddle works fine, you've just spelled `alert` wrong. Here's a [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/mHJnH/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `this` is a reference to the `a` element:

```
var id = $(this).closest(".Actions").prev().attr("id");
```

The [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method climbs up the DOM tree to the first ancestor matching the selector (the `div` is the grandparent of the `a` element), and the [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method gets the immediately preceding element.

Comment: if you use closest() then why not look for .Display? :D

Comment: @GungFoo - Because it's not an ancestor. It's a sibling of the grandparent element.

Comment: $('.Display',$(this).closest('MessageInfo'))

Comment: @GungFoo - Yeah that would work. There are always various ways to achieve the same thing, especially with jQuery.

Comment: i was just wondering because if you use closest() to select the parent, you might aswell just use parent(). Which is because it sounds odd to look for a match after closest() does parent() anyways

Comment: @GungFoo - The parent of the `a` element is the `span`. I'm getting the `div`, which is the grandparent.

Answer (score 1):

you want the "id attribute" of the "previous item" in your anchors "parents parent".

```
$('.like-Unlike').parent().parent().prev().attr('id');
```